# Remap ESC to FN+ESC in Debian TTY

Tags: raspberry-pi, keyboard, tty

I've recently bought a tiny keyboard for my raspberry pi zero w (Raspbian, based on Debian Buster, "lite" edition). However, it has an annoying design, with no Function Keys (F1~F9), and the ESC key in the place of the **~ `** in the US international layout (next to the 1 key). It has no **~** whatsoever, so navigating to home is always a chore.

So, I tried remapping <kbd>ESC</kbd> to <kbd>`</kbd><kbd>~</kbd> and using <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd> in my TTY session. However, as I have no X11, *xev* and *xmodmap* aren't an option. I tried using *loadkeys*, however I can only find documentation about simple replacement, like binding <kbd>ESC</kbd> to key 19, and not combinations like <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd> to produce the desired behavior.

Is there any package for the TTY or set of commands to permanently remap such keys?

Answer (score 3):

afaik the "FN" Key doesn't get communicated to the OS. The switching between the binded keys happens on your keyboard. The OS doesn't know that you're pressing FN+ ESC in any given moment. So you have to figure out which key is on the FN+ESC. Once you know what kind of key your keyboard communicates to the OS you can just switch the ~ with ESC and ESC with whatever key is bindet to FN+ESC currently.

Comment: Besdies, depending on the keyboard, it is possible that `Esc` has no special meaning with `Fn`, it would just communicate `Esc`. If the OP wants to use some `Fn+Key` combination to input `~`, he will have to overwrite a valid, existing one, losing its original "special" function.

Comment: Yes true, I didn't think about that. Most Keyboards have a little symbol on the keys when they have a funktion with `FN`, though. So it should be fairly easy to check most of the times. @user3430483 what keyboard do you exactly use?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! It’s a Motorspeed CK62. I’m back home in a few hours and I’ll try to see if the FN+ESC produces an unique code!